# Не работает псевдокласс - :hover

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

css:

```
body{
    height: 1000px;
}

.main{
    width: 1559px;  
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #06060F, #372669);
    padding: 10px;
}

.to_feed{
    padding-left: 148.9px;
}

.name{
    color: rgba(311, 200, 600, 0.253); 
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 40px;
}

.search{
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-top: 14.4px;
}  

.call{
    padding-left: 11px;
    transform: scale(1);
}

.call:hover{
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

....................

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Галерея</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Галерея.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <header>
            <div class="main" align="left">
                <span class="to_feed"><a href="#">
                    <img src="D:\Сайт\Галерея\Пикчи\Галерея.png"></a>
                </span> 
                <span class="name">Галерея</span>
                <span><input class="search" placeholder="&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp П &nbsp о &nbsp и &nbsp с 
&nbsp к"></span>
            <span><img class="call" height="36.9" width="36.9" 
src="D:\Сайт\Галерея\Пикчи\Увеломлени1.png"></span>
            </div>
        </header>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас в названиях файлов ужас. Никогда не называйте файлы русскими буквами. И пути к картинкам думаю можно было тоже задать относительные.
Перенес ваш код с песочницу, почистил ссылки и все работает:

```css
body{
    height: 1000px;
}

.main{
    width: 1559px;  
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #06060F, #372669);
    padding: 10px;
}

.to_feed{
    padding-left: 148.9px;
}

.name{
    color: rgba(311, 200, 600, 0.253); 
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 40px;
}

.search{
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-top: 14.4px;
}  

.call{
    padding-left: 11px;
    transform: scale(1);
}

.call:hover{
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Галерея</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <header>
            <div class="main" align="left">
                <span class="to_feed"><a href="#">
                    
                <span class="name">Галерея</span>
                <span><input class="search" placeholder="&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp П &nbsp о &nbsp и &nbsp с 
&nbsp к"></span>
            <span><img class="call" height="36.9" width="36.9" 
src="https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/727b797f23a63181d758e7bb2d404bc351d4ad0c/94569/img/og.png"></span>
            </div>
        </header>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```